# Asp Net 5 Web Api token authentication in Angular 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'using Angular 4 + ASP MVC 5 WEB API and I've integrated Token Authentication 
[code from here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1187872/Token-Based-Authentication-for-Web-API-where-Legac) and I can get token from Poster using POST to http://localhost:3590/Token

How to use this authentication in Angular 4?
 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, replace your username, password and port number. You can check the token in session storage.

```
Login():void{
    const body='username=1@1.com&password=Zx123.&grant_type=password';  
    let resp=this.http.post('http://localhost:11694/token',body,
    {observe:'response'}).subscribe(res=>{
    sessionStorage.setItem('myToken',res.body['access_token']);
    }
);
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNYWb.png)